# React build passing but not updating on Heroku with Travis CI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, travis-ci

I've been trying to my React, Express and Node app on Heroku using Travis CI, but can't seem to get the build to automate as I want it too.
My Travis Builds pass and everything looks fine and dandy except for when I look at the dev site on Heroku. Even if it's something as simple as a text change, the heroku build doesn't seem to update the view.

I also don't see a new `/build` folder on my repo after running through the Travis CI build. I can manually create builds and push them to heroku, but that totally takes the fun out of continuous integration for my purpose.

Right now, my file structure looks something like this:
[image]
Here's a [link to the repo](https://github.com/ashishdommety/tutor-times)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share Procfile

Comment: Here's my Procfile: `web: node server.js`

Comment: After running Travis CI, does the build not show up on the repo?

Comment: So I learned that Travis CI doesn't exactly run your build, but 'test-runs' it to check if anything breaks. This makes sense when giving it deeper thought.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured out what the issue was after digging into some of my older projects -

I forgot to add `heroku-postbuild` in my package.json!

I read this [great post by Dave Ceddia](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/) about deploying a react-express application to heroku that reminded me of what I needed to do.

For those who also have this problem, try adding the following at your root:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && yarn && yarn run build"
}
```